# SCTP streams and messages - can I have both?

Tags: sctp

I'm using SCTP, and based on how one opens the SCTP socket, it seems like I can only have streams or messages, depending on sock_seqpacket or sock_stream. Is there any way to have both? (i.e., an SCTP connection running a mix of stream-oriented channels and message-oriented channels?)